# How to hide `<li>` drop down menu in Nav bar in Desktop view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my objective:

In desktop view the "Select Province" menu should disappear.
And then reappear in Mobile View.
**there are two of these. One is a select statement that appears in desktop view. the other is an `<li>` drop down that will appear in mobile**

I am using a custom css + bootstrap. I placed the affected section in a block quote to better understand where my issue is.

I am using mobiletest.me to test for mobile environment.

---

What works: 
In mobile view it drops down to the mobile nav.

If i used `<section class="province-btn-remove"></section>` it works and hides in desktop view--but messes up the styling.

---

What doesn't work:
the Dropdown menu that appears under the nav in desktop view, shouldn't be there, should be hidden.

---

The HTML code:

```
<nav>
     <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

       <li class="left"><a href="http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR?fr_id=[[S80:trID]]" class="home-btn" title="Home">Home</a></li>

       <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events?pg=informational&amp;type=fr_informational&amp;sid=9700&amp;fr_id=[[S80:trID]]" class="tours-btn" title="Register">Register</a></li>

       <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events?pg=pfind&amp;fr_id=[[S80:trID]]" class="about-btn" title="Search participants or teams">Find a Fundraiser</a></li>

       <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events/General?pg=informational&fr_id=21282&type=fr_informational&sid=6583" class="learn-btn" title="Learn more">Learn More</a></li>

       <li class="right"><a href="TR/Events?pg=pfind&amp;fr_id=[[S80:trID]]" class="donater-btn hvr-buzz-out" title="Donate to team or participant">DONATE</a></li>
```

> ```
> <li class="provinces-btn-remove">
>  <li title="Select Province">
>   <li class="provinces-btn">
>      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Province<span class="caret"></span></a> 
>      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
>          <li><a href="#">Alberta</a></li>
>          <li><a href="#">British Columbia</a></li>
>          <li><a href="#">Ontario</a></li>
>          <li><a href="#">Nunavut</a></li>
>          <li><a href="#">Manitoba</a></li>
>      </ul>  
>    </li>
>   </li>
> </li>
> ```

```
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

My CSS code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
    .provinces-btn-remove{
    visibility: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.provinces-btn {

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    margin-left: 0px;


}

    .provinces-btn:hover, .provinces-btnActive {
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
        background: #1975D1;
        font-weight: 900;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 604px) {
.provinces-btn {

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    margin-left: 15px;

   }

 }
```

If you're wondering why I am not just taking the select statement and place it into mobile view is because 1. I don't know how, and 2. I can't style the select statement to match the mobile view navigation. I asked about that in a previous question that remains unanswered.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS (functionally speaking) is written correctly - but the HTML rendered via your link, is not in the same hierarchy as the HTML you pasted above.

You are attempting `visibility: hidden` on the `.provinces-btn-remove` class, but as seen in my screenshot below, it is a sibling to the dropdown, and *not* wrapping the dropdown.

[image: html order]

And a side note, keep your breakpoints at 767px/768px, and not 768px/769px. Bootstrap breaks at the former. You will have 1px problems as you're resizing, if you do not update yours to 767px/768px.

Comment: oh woah i didn't realize it mattered for the px, because when I was testing it on mobiletest.me the ipad mini was giving me issues so I had it increased but good to know thanks I'll fix that.

Comment: @Umeed No problem. Regarding your CSS - you could (instead of updating the HTML), just change `.provinces-btn-remove` to `.provinces-btn` in your rule. Also, if you want to get rid of that nasty whitespace, change `visibility: hidden;` to `display: none;`.

Comment: hmm it's not disappearing. Figures that if it isn't one thing it's another haha. This drop down menu has been taking way longer than it should lol. I think i have something in that menu interfering. I'll try and figure it out. thanks again Jimmy!

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you should simply have to change:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
  .provinces-btn-remove{
  visibility: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

to:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
  .provinces-btn{
  visibility: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

You seem to be targeting a class that has no content, rather than the button you intend

Comment: ! now its hidden, lol i can't believe i didn't try that. Thank you. Just a question, is there a reason that even though its hidden the white space remains? the nave bar doesn't drop back down over the banner

Answer (score 1):

Even after Jimmy Amash answer is correct, if you are using Bootstrap you should use their helper classes for hiding or showing elements according to breakpoints, so using CSS Classes `hidden-md hidden-lg` would accomplish your desired result.

```
<li class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Won't show on desktop breakpoint medium and large </li>
```

The purpose of using a CSS Framework its using most of it classes to help maintain code, as if you change Bootstrap LESS (or SASS) variables to change breakpoints pixel width your code should retain behaviour and rewrite as less as possible.

See [Responsive Utilities on Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for more info about visibility helper classes.